# How to know if I have DDS installed?

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a bit of a noob on ROS2 and I'm starting to learn about the DDS protocol and its implementation on ROS2. So far, I've read that ROS2 already comes with eProsima Fast RTPS, however, I would like to make sure if this is really installed or not. How can I confirm this? Is there a terminal command or something I can do to test it?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349112/how-to-know-if-i-have-dds-installed?/) by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2020-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seeing as you've tagged this `eloquent`: if you've installed ROS 2 using the `deb` repositories on Ubuntu, you could check you have the required packages installed.

For Eloquent, that would be packages like `fastrtps` and `rmw_fastrtps_cpp` (see [repo.ros2.org/status_page/ros_eloquent_default.html?q=fast](http://repo.ros2.org/status_page/ros_eloquent_default.html?q=fast) for all packages).

To check you have those installed, you could use a command like this:

```
dpkg -l | grep fastrt
```

Note btw: this will not show you "whether you have DDS installed", it will show you whether you have the FastRTPS packages installed. Pedantic, but those contain only a single implementation of DDS. There are quite a few more, but those are not distributed by default with ROS 2.

---

Edit: from your screenshot it appears you have built ROS 2 from source. In that case the `dpkg` command I included earlier will not help you.

For source installs, you'll want to check you:

1. have the Fast RTPS sources in your workspace
2. they have been built during the overall ROS 2 build (with Colcon)
3. the `install` space has the Fast RTPS libraries in the `lib` sub folder.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on 2020-04-11**:
Hey! Thank you for your answer. Below I included a print of my eProsima folder. Does this mean that I have fast-rtps installed and that I am able to communicate with a different machine?
https://prnt.sc/rxaepi
Thank you again

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-11**:
I've updated my answer.

In the future: please always include pertinent details such as how you've installed ROS, which OS you're using, which version, etc. Without such information, we can only guess (which is what I did).

Furthermore: you appear to be using Ubuntu: I'd sugget to make sure you need to build ROS 2 from sources, as using the binary packages would be much faster and more efficient.

**Comment by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on 2020-04-11**:
Alright, sorry for that. I installed by source because for some reason I couldn't install it from debian.
Regarding, your edit, I have a couple of questions:

1. I don't have any Fast RTPS folder inside my ros workspace. Does this mean that it's not installed afterall?
2. I believe that when I first made the overall ROS2 build, everything ran smoothly
3. What do you mean with this third bullet point?
   Thank you again

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-11**:\

> I installed by source because for some reason I couldn't install it from debian.

Somewhat off-topic, but I would suggest to figure out why you couldn't, as installing `.deb`s is typically a couple of minutes, while building from source often takes much more time.

You'll have to build *everything* from source now.

> I don't have any Fast RTPS folder inside my ros workspace. Does this mean that it's not installed afterall?

This confuses me: you just showed a screenshot with the `eProsima/Fast-RTPS` folder in your `ros2_eloquent` `src` folder. Is that not your ROS 2 workspace?

> What do you mean with this third bullet point?

After you build ROS 2, there will be an `install` folder next to the `src` folder in your `ros2_eloquent` workspace root. The `lib` sub folder of that should contain the Fast RTPS libraries.

But really, all of this is somewhat unnecessary, as, if:

1. your build was successful, and
2. you can run things like the `ros2 topic list`

things should be OK.

**Comment by [anonymous53443](https://answers.ros.org/users/53443/anonymous53443/) on 2020-04-11**:
Okay okay got it!
I thought you were talking about the workspace where I keep the packages I create.
Anyway, thank you very much for your tips and your overall help! :)